# SwiftUI make a Text partly tappable

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I trying to build an app that having a list that contained some information. I tried to make information partly tappable while the information contained a mobile number or maybe URL? I want to know may it be possible to do so?

For example the URL and mobile in the list

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var itemList : [Item] = [Item]()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List(itemList){ item in
                Text(item.info)
            }
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            print("test")
            itemList = [Item(info: "testing"), Item(info: "Contact me 0123456789"), Item(info: "Check our website https://google.com")]
        })

    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var info : String
    let id = UUID()
    func load() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean like attributed string, then no (not now) - use UIKit components instead wrapped in representable.

Comment: @Asperi Thank you for your comment. I will try it.